# fbprophet: Predict a future holiday

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have time series data with holidays in it. I would like my model to predict an upcoming holiday. However, it seems my model is predicting the general trend and not allocating an increase where there is a holiday.

Is there a way for me to specify future dates as a holiday? I thought adding it into the holiday variable would ensure it is in the model/forecast.

Here's some dummy data to test:
I have data from January 1st 2017 to today (November 16th 2018). There are holidays (sales) every two months. The upcoming holiday (sale) is in December. I would like to predict the upcoming December holiday. The code is overly verbose but hopefully it helps with clarity.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet

times = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2018-11-16')
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 366 - 0.28))
noise = 15 * np.random.rand(annual_cycle.size)
data = 10 + (5 * annual_cycle) + noise
s = pd.Series(data, index=times)
# Add holiday data in
s.loc['2017-02-01':'2017-02-03'] = s.loc['2017-02-01':'2017-02-03'] * 3
s.loc['2017-04-01':'2017-04-03'] = s.loc['2017-04-01':'2017-04-03'] * 3
s.loc['2017-06-01':'2017-06-03'] = s.loc['2017-06-01':'2017-06-03'] * 3
s.loc['2017-08-01':'2017-08-03'] = s.loc['2017-08-01':'2017-08-03'] * 3
s.loc['2017-10-01':'2017-10-03'] = s.loc['2017-10-01':'2017-10-03'] * 3
s.loc['2017-12-01':'2017-12-03'] = s.loc['2017-12-01':'2017-12-03'] * 3
s.loc['2018-02-01':'2018-02-03'] = s.loc['2018-02-01':'2018-02-03'] * 3
s.loc['2018-04-01':'2018-04-03'] = s.loc['2018-04-01':'2018-04-03'] * 3
s.loc['2018-06-01':'2018-06-03'] = s.loc['2018-06-01':'2018-06-03'] * 3
s.loc['2018-08-01':'2018-08-03'] = s.loc['2018-08-01':'2018-08-03'] * 3
s.loc['2018-10-01':'2018-10-03'] = s.loc['2018-10-01':'2018-10-03'] * 3
# s.plot()

df = s.to_frame().reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={"index": "ds", 0: "y"})

# Specify a holidays Series
hol1 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol1',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='2/01/2017', end='2/03/2017')})
hol2 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol2',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='4/01/2017', end='4/03/2017')})
hol3 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol3',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='6/01/2017', end='6/03/2017')})
hol4 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol4',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='8/01/2017', end='8/03/2017')})
hol5 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol5',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='10/01/2017', end='10/03/2017')})
hol6 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol6',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='12/01/2017', end='12/03/2017')})
hol7 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol7',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='2/01/2018', end='2/03/2018')})
hol8 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol8',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='4/01/2018', end='4/03/2018')})
hol9 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol9',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='6/01/2018', end='6/03/2018')})
hol10 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol10',
                      'ds': pd.date_range(start='8/01/2018', end='8/03/2018')})
hol11 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol11',
                      'ds': pd.date_range(start='10/01/2018', end='10/03/2018')})
# Future holiday
hol12 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol12',
                      'ds': pd.date_range(start='12/01/2018', end='12/03/2018')})
holidays = pd.concat([hol1, hol2, hol3, hol4, hol5, hol6, hol7, hol8, hol9, hol10, hol11, hol12])

m = Prophet(holidays=holidays)
m.fit(df)

# Predict up until the end of the next holiday
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=17)
future.tail()

forecast = m.predict(future)

fig1 = m.plot(forecast)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're told it that each date is a separate holiday, by putting each holiday in a separate column. So it think that the new holiday you have in December 2018 is a separate event unrelated to any of the previous ones.

You need to put all of the related holidays (or sales events) all in one column of the dataframe.

Comment: ```hol1 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='2/01/2017', end='2/03/2017')})
hol2 = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': 'hol',
                     'ds': pd.date_range(start='4/01/2017', end='4/03/2017')}) # etc``` worked for me